# show List Tile after clicking on button flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

I have an Elevatebutton where I want to do that when I click on it, I can see a listTile displayed and after I click on another button the listTile will disappear. I have the code written like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: ( ) {
                          setState(() {
                            ListTile(
                              leading: Icon(Icons.add),
                              title: Text('GFG title',textScaleFactor: 1.5,),
                              trailing: Icon(Icons.done),
                            );
                          });
                        },
                        child: Text('button1'),
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(shape: StadiumBorder()),
                      ),
```

but even when I click on the button I do not see the listTile. How do I fix this? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When pressing the button you can't just write a widget and it will appear. One thing you can do is to already have the ListTile in the view but it's invisible. Then when you press the button it becomes visible. Here's an example:

```
bool _isVisible = false;

...
...

Column(
        children: [ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _isVisible = true;
            });
          },
          child: Text('button1'),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(shape: StadiumBorder()),
        ),

          Visibility(
              visible: _isVisible,
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.add),
                title: Text('GFG title', textScaleFactor: 1.5,),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.done),
              ))
        ],
      )
```

Comment: I tried doing that but i still dont see the listTile

Comment: @newbieperson Check out this code in dartpad, it should work: https://dartpad.dev/?id=48f17ff57444f99f35abd9e3ca5eb0da

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

Decalre bool variable

```
bool buttonPressed = false;
```

Your Widget:

```
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          buttonPressed
              ? ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.add),
                  title: Text(
                    'GFG title',
                    textScaleFactor: 1.5,
                  ),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.done),
                )
              : Container(),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("Show Widget"),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                buttonPressed = true;
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: this is showing ListTile() part to be deadcode

Comment: @newbieperson what do you exact want when you pressed the button it will display the `ListTile` as per your requirnment